# Template argument deduction in case of designated initializers in C++

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++20, aggregate-initialization

In the following code there is an initialization of `A<T>` objects with template argument deduction using designated initializers in two slightly distinct forms:

```
template<typename T>
struct A { T t; };

int main() {
   A a{.t=1};   //#1: ok in GCC and MSVC
   A b{.t={1}}; //#2: ok in MSVC only
}
```

The first way is accepted by both GCC and MSVC, while the second one is ok for MSVC only while GCC prints errors:

```
error: class template argument deduction failed:
error: no matching function for call to 'A(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/PaEaMjM7q

Which compiler is right there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GCC is correct. Braced-init-list like `{1}` has no type, so it makes [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts) fail.

> Non-deduced contexts
>
> ...
>
> The parameter P, whose A is `a braced-init-list, but P is not std::initializer_list, a reference to one (possibly cv-qualified), or (since C++17)` a reference to an array: